# How to use multi SQLAlchemy session for a web application?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using multi mysql database for a web application. For each database, I want to use a separate SQLAlchemy session.

This is what I do:

```
engine1 = create_engine(DB_URL_1)
db_session1 = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine1))
engine2 = create_engine(DB_URL_2)
db_session2 = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine2))
```

Is it right? Is there better way to make it?

and what is the different between `normal session` and `scoped session`?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. You may also want to set the `scopefunc` on `scoped_session` to be per-request instead of per-thread.